# VPN Cisco IPSec change DNS

Tags: macos, dns, vpn, cisco, ipsec

When I make connection vpn on macos (10.14.4) my dns will be change.
with normal wifi connection:

```
# bash-3.2# cat /etc/resolv.conf
# macOS Notice
#
# This file is not consulted for DNS hostname resolution, address
# resolution, or the DNS query routing mechanism used by most
# processes on this system.
#
# To view the DNS configuration used by this system, use:
#   scutil --dns
#
# SEE ALSO
#   dns-sd(1), scutil(8)
#
# This file is automatically generated.
#
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

with vpn connection:

```
bash-3.2# cat /etc/resolv.conf
#
# macOS Notice
#
# This file is not consulted for DNS hostname resolution, address
# resolution, or the DNS query routing mechanism used by most
# processes on this system.
#
# To view the DNS configuration used by this system, use:
#   scutil --dns
#
# SEE ALSO
#   dns-sd(1), scutil(8)
#
# This file is automatically generated.
#
nameserver 10.80.3.1
```

I don't want change nameserver. 
I wonder why does it change and how to fix?

Answer (score -1):

its set by the Cisco, like

```
username USER attributes
 vpn-group-policy POLICY

group-policy POLICY
 dns-server value 10.8.3.1
```

not sure if you can override it by system -> network -> your-vpn -> options -> dns..